# Issue tracking for mass produced products

Tags: web-apps, issue-tracker

I'm on a hunt for a system to track issues of a mass produced product.

The main difference from usual bug trackers for software (Atlassian Jira/Service Desk, Bugzilla, GitHub Issues) is the need to list common issues and the possibility to say *me too* (and to create a new issue first when it is not already present).

#### Requirements

- Web based, all operation through a web browser.
- Front page to display a list of known issues (possible by means of a plugin or configuration; this is the main purpose of the system).
- Users may submit a new issue with attachments (pictures suffice). Submitted issues
- Search through the issues.
- Selected users can act es editors, i.e. edit, merge, delete issues (admin group, privilege settings etc.).
- Can be hosted in a public hosting service, virtual server or cloud service (with reasonable fees, i.e. not to consume hours of processor for every search); or comes as a managed solution.
- Self hosted option free of charge (preferably FOSS), managed solution for only a small fee (maximum tens €/$ per month).

#### Other figures

Single (English) language, expected number of products is up to ten (one would suffice as well), expected number of users (issue reporters) in thousands (max. lower tens of thousands) with one to ten issues per user.

#### Use case

A startup introduces a product through a crowd funding campaign. The first production run for the early backers still has issues that escaped quality control, and the manufacturer needs to know which wrinkles to iron before the further production commences. One issue only appears in one country, but affects all users who happen to be there. Other issue affects half of produced units,  is overlooked by the first backers as a negligible nuisance and is not widely reported, but would be taken badly by customers (compared to the crowdfunding campaign backers).